# Cannot write file using scrapy executed from flask os.system() function on openshift

Tags: python, file, flask, scrapy, openshift

I am trying to run scrapy on openshift flask server with os.system("scrapy crawl spiderName") and my spider in pipeline opens the file and each item saves to it. When I run scrapy in rhc console everything works fine, but when I am trying run it over the url (flask) then it does not create the file. I think there must be something wrong with permissions or paths, but I tried almost everything (permissions to folder, absolute paths to the files) without success.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can only write files to the data dir, which is in `app-root/data` and can be referenced with the environment variable `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR`.